# How can I know in entity framework the source of view's column

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to know in `Entity Framework` the sources of column of view (I need to display them)
**for example:**
    CRMEntity crm=new CRMEntity();
crm has a `fullTable` view 
and this is its script:

```
create view [dbo].[FullTable]
as
select c.iCustomerId,c.id,sum(p.iPoints) sumPoints ,
a.nvCity,a.nvNeighberwood,a.nvStreet,a.iHouseNum,a.nvEnterance,a.iFloor,a.nvNote
from tbl_Customer c 
join Point p on p.iCustomerId=c.iCustomerId 
join tbl_Address a on a.iAddressId=c.iAddressId 
group by p.iCustomerId,c.id,c.iCustomerId,c.nvCellolar,c.nvFirstName,c.nvLastName,c.nvPhone,
a.nvCity,a.nvNeighberwood,a.nvStreet,a.iHouseNum,a.nvEnterance,a.iFloor,a.nvNote
```

and view `computedColumns` view and this is its script:

```
create view [dbo].[computedColumns]
as
select a.iAddressId+a.iAddressId cmp1,STR(a.nvCity,0,5) cmp2,333 cmp3,a.iFloor+1 cmp5 from tbl_Address a
```

(all of the selections are from tables)
I want to know for each columns its sources

for `computedColumns`:

```
cmp1->tbl_Address.iAddressId 
cmp2->tbl_Address.nvCity
cmp3->null
cmp5 ->tbl_Address.iFloor
```

for `FullTable`:

```
iCustomerId->tbl_Customer.iCustomerId
id->tbl_Customer.id 
sumPoints ->Point .sumPoints 
and Etc
```

Comment: The source is where something comes from. You seem to know that already (eg, id has `tbl_Customer.id` as its source), so what is your question?

Comment: Please, be more specific on what you're trying to achieve and try to condense your code examples as much as you can.

Comment: Where a `view` gets its data from is not exposed directly to EF.  If you want to know the source for each column in the view, you'll have to refer to the view's DDL.

Comment: Amy -thank you for your comment but it isn't help me -I need to know the source column for each column, and these views are just for example